# How is 床 related to 临床 and 东床?

Tags: meaning-in-context

床 is bed, on which people sleep or lie.

But 临床 has the connection with medical profession and 东床 seems to be in relation to in-laws, but why is so? Because these two do not have any express features of sleeping or work which needs to be done in bed.

Comment: 床 bkrs：bed, couch; framework, chassis e。g。车床 lathe; turning machine; turning lathe; turning mill:东床（女婿） son-in-law cf。bkrs：  **坦腹东床**  ：旧作女婿的美称：be a worthy son-in-law of sb.
1) ideal son-in-law
2) lie in bed with bared belly。临床{医} clinical:接触病人, 诊治疾病 （close to bed on which there is a patient)

Comment: Thanks, but you haven't told me the reason why it is so. Why is a son-in-law called something in relation to a bed? Is that bed his position to stay at home or what?

Comment: evidently 坦腹东床 describes modest unassuming behavior characterizing ideal son-in-law, web search will yield further explanation https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%9D%A6%E8%85%B9%E4%B8%9C%E5%BA%8A

Answer (score 4):

> The term '临床' means "in front of the patient's bed or operation bed "

- '临' (facing/ in front of)
- '床' ( bed) here refers to '手术床'(operation bed) or 病床 (patient's bed)
- '临床经验' means 'clinical experience'

> The term '东床' came from the idiom 东床快婿,

The story of [东床快婿](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%9C%E5%BA%8A%E5%BF%AB%E5%A9%BF):

> 郄鉴 heard the sons of 王导 were all handsome gentleman. So, he wanted to marry his daughter to one of them. For that very reason, 郄鉴 sent a messenger to 王导's house to observe the young men in 王导's household in order to select one of them to be his son-in-law.
>
> The messenger reported to 郄鉴 that all of them were pleasant gentleman and showed him great respect -- except for one.  There was one bare-chested young man lay there in a bed on the east side of the room,  ignoring all the commotion. 郄鉴 decided this bare-chested young man on the East-side bed was the finest young man among 王导's sons, and should be the husband of his daughter.
>
> That bare-chested man on the East bed turned out to be the famous [王羲之](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Xizhi) (Wang Xizhi).

That's the story of how '东床' (East bed) became a symbol of "worthy son-in-law"

- in '东床快婿', '东床'(East bed)= '快婿'( a pleasant son-in-law)

Answer (score 1):

Tang Ho has basically answered this already, I’ll just give what I have.

临床 is the same as the English *bedside* as in *bedside manner* of doctors.

东床 is explained in A Chinese-English dictionary as:

> NOUN
>
> eastern bed—son-in-law (from an anecdote about the celebrated calligrapher Wang Xizhi 王羲之 (321-379), who as a young man remained eating bare chested on the eastern bed when an official came to choose a son-in-law for the minister's daughter, and who was selected for his independence of mind over his well-behaved brothers)
>
> 东床快婿
>
> dōngchuángkuàixù
>
> a good son-in-law

So, yes, as you said 床 just means *bed*.